# Project Euler 348: Sum of a square and a cube

Tags: python, performance, programming-challenge, palindrome

> Many numbers can be expressed as the sum of a square and a cube. Some of them in more than one way.
>
> Consider the palindromic numbers that can be expressed as the sum of a
>   square and a cube, both greater than 1, in exactly 4 different ways.
>   For example, 5229225 is a palindromic number and it can be expressed
>   in exactly 4 different ways:
>
> 2285<sup>2</sup> + 20<sup>3</sup>
>
> 2223<sup>2</sup> + 66<sup>3</sup>
>
> 1810<sup>2</sup> + 125<sup>3</sup>
>
> 1197<sup>2</sup> + 156<sup>3</sup>
>
> Find the sum of the five smallest such palindromic numbers.

I used brute force; it solves in around 11 seconds. I thought about it for some time but couldn't come up with any obvious optimizations, the problem seems built for brute force. Any suggestions?

**Note that I'm using PyPy which makes math code run much faster...**

```
"""Find the sum of the five smallest palindromic numbers
that can be expressed as the sum of a square and a cube."""

from math import log10
from collections import Counter
from timeit import default_timer as timer

def is_palindrome(n):
    length = int(log10(n))
    while length > 0:
        right = n % 10
        left = n / 10**length
        if right != left:
            return False
        n %= 10**length
        n /=10
        length -= 2
    return True

start = timer()
palindromes = Counter()

for square in xrange(1, 30000):
    squared = square**2
    for cube in xrange(1, 3000):
        cubed = cube**3
        total = squared + cubed
        if is_palindrome(total): palindromes[total] += 1

ans = sum(x[0] for x in palindromes.most_common(5))
elapsed_time = timer() - start
print "Found %d in %d s." % (ans, elapsed_time)
```

Comment: I can't test it, but how well does your `is_palindrome` match up to [the string version](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17331290/359284) on PyPy?

Answer (score 1):

@Kevin Brown is correct, your programme runs in 18 seconds on my PC, if I write:

```
def is_palindrome(n):
    return str(n) == str(n)[::-1]
```

it takes only 16 seconds.

Comment: You using PyPy? On my computer it runs in around 20s with that version.